# How to type plain object as having strings for keys

Tags: typescript

I there any way to tell this code that `k` is a string, i'd think that the typing for `V` would suffice?

```
function example <V extends { [key: string]: any }>(value: V, k: keyof V ): string { 
    return k;
}
```

I'd like not to cast any here, this example, yes it's possible, but in my other cases I simply want TS to know it's a string.

I'd expect a type error if the keys are numbers, however this is valid:

```
example({ 1: true }, 1)
```

Comment: I think you can't do that because Typescript assumes every object key always converted to a string, that's why it didn't show an error. Based on this assumption and on condition that index type can only be number | string you can use within the function and return from it k.toString() expression.

Answer (score 0):

## The Answer

```
k: keyof V & string
```

## The Explanation

`V extends { [key: string]: any }` really means... Whatever object having at least one property of type `string`. This means `keyof V` is really the equivalent of `PropertyKey`. That is whywe need to intersected whatever key type in there with the `string` type.

So the following will be valid:

(1)

```
let value: { [key: string]: any } = {
    abc: 'AaBbCc',
    [Symbol()]: 123,
};
```

(2)

```
value: { [key: string]: any } = {}; // Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty, for eg.
```

What is not to be valid is:

(1)

```
let value: { [key: string]: any } = undefined;
```

(2)

```
let value: { [key: string]: any } = null;
```

## Other Considerations

For simple types that map to simple values, consider `Record` (if your version of TypeScript) allows you to. eg.: `Record<string, any>`.

In the case you didn't mean to restrict the `k` parameter to `string`, as well as the return value, consider the builtin type `PropertyKey` which is really `string | number | symbol` or rewrite your contract to some equivalent of...

```
function example <V, K extends keyof V>(value: V, k: K ): K { 
    return k;
}
```